# AVAudioEngine documentation

Tags: avaudioengine

I'm trying to find a detailed documentation for how to work with AVAudioEngine. Does anyone know where I can find it?

I've found this, but it seems extremely spartan in comparison to the richly documented UI stuff.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioengine

Is this it? Are there header files somewhere I can at least peruse, like there was with AUGraph (before they deprecated it).

Answer (score 3):

You can also try Apple's official sample code at

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AVAEMixerSample/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015134-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: There's also a Swift version of that here: https://github.com/ooper-shlab/AVAEMixerSample-Swift

Answer (score 1):

The link you provided should be enough to be able to work with AVAudioEngine. If you go to the parent page of AVAudioEngine, that can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudioengine/), you can see all the building blocks you need to work with the audio.

Comment: That link "cannot be found" boooo.

Comment: @NerdyBunz Seems they have changed the routes in the docs without redirecting the old links. I've updated the answer, so the link should be there in a moment :)